# How divide the mutable array into mutable subarrays

Tags: arrays, rust, mutable

I need to divide the mutablearray into 3 mutablesubarrays with mutable elements.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    time: i64
}


impl Server {
    fn new(x: i64) -> Server {
        return Server {
            time: x
        }
    } 
}

fn main() {
      let mut arr = Vec::<Server>::new();
      arr.push(Server::new(10));
      arr.push(Server::new(20));
      arr.push(Server::new(30));
      arr.push(Server::new(40));
      arr.push(Server::new(50));

      let mut arr1 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time > 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
      let mut arr2 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time < 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
      let mut arr3 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time == 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
}
```

Next, over each subarray to carry out different manipulations that do not affect the main array. (For example, each subarray is first sorted without affecting the order of the main array. The next step is to manipulate its elements over each subarray. And these changes should be reflected in the elements of the main array).

At the moment, when dividing the array Rust when compiling, it gives the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `arr` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:26:18
   |
25 |   let mut arr1 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time > 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
   |                  --- first mutable borrow occurs here
26 |   let mut arr2 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time < 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
   |                  ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
 ...
29 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `arr` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:27:18
   |
25 |   let mut arr1 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time > 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
   |                  --- first mutable borrow occurs here
26 |   let mut arr2 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time < 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
27 |   let mut arr3 = arr.iter_mut().filter(|x| x.time == 20).collect::<Vec<&mut Server>>();
   |                  ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
28 |   
29 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to use interior mutability, `Vec<RefCell<Server>>`.

Comment: As a sidenote: Idiomatic rust does not use `return` as last statement (`return Server { time: x }`), but instead just write `Server { time: x }` (as you can see in my playground example).

Comment: If you care about speed, do this manually and potentially in-place.

Comment: @Veedrac "in-place" doesn't make any sense in this context, because you need a second `vec` for storing the other elements. (Just a curious question: are you familar with rust?).
Also the implementation of [`partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#1500-1517) is very straight forward and would be the easiest to implement solution without using fancy `unsafe` stuff.

Comment: @hellow You can partition in place and then work over subslices of your vector. Like [`itertools::partition`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/fn.partition.html) but a 3-way partition. [`[T]::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap) makes it possible to partition efficiently with safe code. Yes I am familiar with Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Iterator::partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) to split up your `vec` into two distinct `vec`s without cloning the inner elements.
Because you want three different splits, you have to use `partition` twice (the order doesn't matter).

```
const THRESHOLD: i64 = 20;

let mut arr = Vec::<Server>::new();
arr.push(Server::new(10));
arr.push(Server::new(20));
arr.push(Server::new(30));
arr.push(Server::new(40));
arr.push(Server::new(50));

let (greater, rest): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = arr.into_iter().partition(|s| s.time > THRESHOLD);
let (equal, less): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = rest.into_iter().partition(|s| s.time == THRESHOLD);
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec7b0f1bc5c99d46e073603a8f8a1573))

Because the Vectors `greater`, `equal` and `less` own the corresponding elements, you have mutable access to them.

Comment: As a note to the code: I would suggest using the [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) macro, instead of the tedious `push`, e.g. `let arr = vec![Server::new(10), Server::new(20), Server::new(30), Server::new(40), Server::new(50)];`

Comment: Note however that this answer moves the items into the iterators, so it doesn't cover the last part of the question: _these changes should be reflected in the elements of the main array._

Comment: @Jmb you're right, but I'm afraid apart from using `RefCells` and a simple `filter` this isn't possible. My solution shows the (IMHO) best solution how to deal with this problem. To reflect the changes to the 'main array' I would just collect all three arrays into one again.

Comment: @hellow I think this decision is wrong: _To reflect the changes to the 'main array' I would just collect all three arrays into one again_. Because i wrote that each subarray can be sorted. Maybe the only right way is to use `RefCells` and `filter`

Comment: `let mut arr: Vec<_> = vec![10, 20, 30, 40, 50].into_iter().map(Server::new).collect();` is cool too.

Comment: @hellow, I solved the problem. I used `RefCell` and `borrow 'system'`. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c63b80a44b77b533d7bb9c609928e5ae)). Thanks to everyone.